# How to display ui-boostrap tooltip on disabled button?

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap-3, tooltip, angular-ui-bootstrap, disabled-input

before posting here i searched and searched and i found several solutions for applying tooltips to disabled buttons, anyway none of these was using `uib-tooltip` from [angular ui bootstrap](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/).

Here is the code of my button:

```
<button class="btn btn-default"
        uib-tooltip="My tooltip text"
        tooltip-append-to-body="true"
        ng-disabled="!isAllSelected"
        ng-click="doThat()">Click Here
</button>
```

Do you know how to make tooltip displayable even when the button is disabled?

Comment: I dont think it will work as if button is disabled no event will get fired. Better is disable button using CSS by adding class.

Comment: you should wrap the button into an element. after that you can activate the tooltip for the element.

Answer (score 10):

Similar to janosch's solution - wrap your button in a div which has the tooltip attribute.

```
<div uib-tooltip="{{ isDisabled ? 'Button is disabled' : '' }}">
   <button disabled="isDisabled">Button</button>
</div>
```

The tooltip will only be visible when the variable `isDisabled` is true, which also sets the `disabled` status of the button.

This solution will also work if you are using the `title` attribute instead of `uib-tooltip`

Comment: Make sure to disable the pointer-events, as demonstrated in this answer. Otherwise the tooltip will not work properly: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40147917/2698694

Answer (score 3):

I don't think it's possible on a button, but it works if you use link disguised as a button, instead of a button:

```
<a class="btn btn-default"
   uib-tooltip="My tooltip text"
   tooltip-append-to-body="true"
   ng-disabled="!isAllSelected"
   ng-click="doThat()">Click Here
</a>
```

Comment: the downside to this is that a non-input or non-button element like <a> tag does not care about the disabled attribute and will still be clickable.

Comment: if you do this, as the first comment says, as well as another answer, you need a conditional inside the ngClick,   like 
`ng-click="isAllSelected && doThat()"`

Answer (score 2):

Simplest, least intrusive solution to this is:

```
<a class="btn btn-default"
    uib-tooltip="My tooltip text"
    tooltip-append-to-body="true"
    ng-disabled="!isAllSelected"
    ng-click="isAllSelected ? doThat() : null">Click Here
</a>
```

(notice conditional `ng-click`, without which clicks will still go through even when anchor is "disabled" - i.e. anchors don't support disabled attribute)

Comment: In this way you are introducing some logic in the view and this is the wrong approach for MVC applications.

Comment: just illustrating the need for the condition - trivial to place inside `doThat`

Answer (score 2):

I know this question is several years old however someone might find useful this workaround.

What I did was to wrap the button content in a `<span>` tag and apply the uib-tooltip to it:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="foo()" ng-disabled="true">
    <span uib-tooltip="Tooltip text" tooltip-append-to-body="true"> Button text<span>
</button>
```

If you also need the tooltip to be shown when the user hovers over the whole button area, you can also remove the button padding and add it to the `<span>` instead.

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="foo()" ng-disabled="true" style="padding: 0px !important;">
    <span uib-tooltip="Tooltip text" tooltip-append-to-body="true" style="display:inline-block; padding: 5px 10px;"> Button text<span>
</button>
```

Answer (score -1):

Irrespective of button being enabled or disabled, I am getting the uib tool tip. The below code is working fine for me.

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-default" ng-click="toggleMin()" ng-disabled = "true" uib-tooltip="After today restriction" >Min date</button>
```

Please see this [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/GpfztPwf67dQ5omdbn6y?p=preview)

Added screenshot of tooltip [image]

**Additional notes:** You can also configure the position of tooltip. All you need to do is to take the help of `$uibTooltipProvider`. We can then use config section to achieve the result. Below code is included in the plunker.

```
angular.module('ui.bootstrap.demo')
.config(['$uibTooltipProvider', function ($uibTooltipProvider) {
    $uibTooltipProvider.options({
        'placement':'bottom'
    });
}])
```

Comment: Ehm... i tried your code but none tooltip is displayed on your disabled button.

Comment: What version of angular.js, boostrap.css and angularanimate.js are you using? What browswer?

Comment: I'm trying on your plunker example. There is no tooltip on disabled button.

Comment: added screenshot for your reference

Comment: Nothing here: it displays the disabled icon on the button, i tried with firefox and chrome.

Comment: The same happens on my friend's computer: no tooltip is displayed.

Comment: I am using FF 44.02 and it is working. It is not working in chrome for me as well. Am not sure why though. May be it has some issues

Comment: I'm using FF 38 and my friend has FF 44.0.2. This is very weird :(